# Update tableView when images loaded asynchronously

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, parse-platform

I get images asynchronously with parse, and i insert them into an array with some other stuff.

I return this array to fill a tableView, and the rows has an `UIImageView`, but some images that i get asynchronously doest get loaded when i fill the table with the array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, so when i first look the tableView, i get the rows with an empty image in the cell, till i move the scroll in the tableView so `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called again and those images i was set in the array are already loaded.

I get the images also if i do a IBAction with `[self.tableView reloadData];` i get the images.

The problem is that i return the cell inmediatelly and the image is not loaded.
I'm using a custom TableViewCell.
I found something about ["AsyncImageView"](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView) to load the image, but i dont know how.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    //Get the game for the row
    GameModel *game = [self.currentMatches objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //HERE i load the images

    MatchCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GameCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   cell.userImage.image = game.avatarp1; //I set the image to the cell but isnt loaded yet

   //If i do this WORKS but i get 2 times the same image (on the game and now) (its a function that i created, that seems is calling tableView or so when assigns the image to the cell, i dont understand why it works 
        [ParseModel getAvatarWithUser:game.p1 completionBlock:^(UIImage *avatar) {
            cell.userImage.image = avatar;
        }];
```

Comment: just do this [yourtableView reloadData];

Answer (score 0):

What if you set to `nil` the image when you get the dequeueReusableCell, and then let the block set the image?

Just change this:

```
cell.userImage.image = game.avatarp1;
```

For this:

```
cell.userImage.image = nil;
```

And then let this code works (I have understood by your answer that this works well)

```
[ParseModel getAvatarWithUser:game.p1 completionBlock:^(UIImage *avatar) {
        cell.userImage.image = avatar;
}];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The problem is that i set the images in an array (ALL the images), and then i have to do this [ParseModel getAvatar.., and load AGAIN the same imagen (2 times). Its not necessary to assign nil to the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)" as an alternative to "[AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView)" that you mentioned in your question. It is very easy to implement. I put here an example of my own code, where I download an image from a URL in a cell in the same way you are trying. (Change my "view" for your cell.userImage)

This method puts a temp image (placeholder and when the image is fully downloaded, it automaticlly changes (without any reload or scroll).

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 238.0f, 289.0f)] autorelease];
        //here is where you put a placeholder and download in the background the image with an URL. Items is an array of URLs
        [(UIImageView *)view setImageWithURL:[items objectAtIndex:index]
              placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
        view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    }
    return view;
}
```

When you have added SDWebImage to your project, dont forget to add into your .m:  #import < SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h >